# Xrm.Page.getAttribute returning null

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I am trying to do a filter for a lookup that is based upon what is in the job and candidate fields. When grabbing attributes for job and candidate it keeps returning null even though there are values in those fields. I also then get an error :

```
Query Builder Error. 
The specified record type does not exist in Microsoft Dynamics 365.
```

I even tried doing `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_joborder").getValue()` and it returns cant get value of null.

Any idea on what is going on here?

```js
function CustomPpcLookupView() {
    // Some GUID but only needs to be unique among the other available views for the lookup
    var viewId = "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}";
    var viewDisplayName = "PPC records for this contact";

    //Only need ppc records for the selected candidate and job order
    var jobOrder = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_joborder");
    var candidate = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_candidate");
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(jobOrder);
    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(candidate);
    if (!jobOrder) { return; }
    if (!jobOrder[0]) { return; }
    if (!jobOrder[0].id) { return; }
    if (!candidate) { return; }
    if (!candidate[0]) { return; }
    if (!candidate[0].id) { return; }

    //Get all approved ppcs that pertain to the selected joborder,candidate 
    var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" +
       "<entity name='hc_candidateppc'>" +
        "<attribute name='hc_candidateppcid' />" +
        "<attribute name='hc_ppc_name' />" +
                    "<attribute name='createdon' />" +
                    "<order attribute='hc_ppc_name' descending='false' />" +
                    "<filter type='and'>" +
                       " <condition attribute='hc_approved' operator='eq' value='948050002' />" +

                       " <condition attribute='hc_candidate' operator='eq' value='" + candidate[0].id + " uitype='contact'  />" +
                       "<condition attribute='hc_joborder' operator='eq'  value='" + jobOrder[0].id + " uitype='hc_joborder'  />" +

                          " <condition attribute='hc_approvalstatusmanager' operator='eq' value='948050001' />" +
                         "<condition attribute='hc_approvalstatusleadership' operator='eq' value='948050001' />" +

                 "</filter>" +
                 "</entity>" +
             "</fetch>";
    //Set up the whole view's UI
    var layoutXml = "<grid name='resultset' object='1' jump='hc_contract' select='1' icon='1' preview='2'>" +
      "<row name='result' id='contractid'>" +
       "<cell name='hc_candidateppcid' width='300' />" +
       "<cell name='hc_ppc_name' width='200' />" +
       "<cell name='createdon' width='100' />" +

      "</row>" +
     "</grid>";

    try {
        //Set the view
        Xrm.Page.getControl("hc_candidateppc").addCustomView(viewId, "hc_candidateppc ", viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);
    } catch (e) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog("Error: " + e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to get the value from a lookup you should do `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_joborder").getValue()`. If it's saying that `Xrm.Page.getAttribute("hc_joborder")` then you probably do not have this field on the form. Paste some screenshot of how your form looks like. Secondly based on the error you get you are referring to non-existing entity so probably you misspelled something. Make sure your fetchXML is correct, crea it in Advanced Find and download FetchXML from there

Comment: Also you have a misspell here `"hc_candidateppc "` you hsould not have whitespace in there